# Adding a formula to an existing formula

Tags: excel-formula

I have this formula that works great for me

```
=IFERROR(SUM(J14*K14)*(1-N14)
```

However, I would like to add an additional portion to this formula that would check another cell for a `Y` and if it does it will ad 50, if it does not contain a `Y` then it will do nothing. I came up with this

```
=IFERROR(SUM(J14*K14)*(1-N14),"")+IF((O14="Y"),50,"")
```

which works but will produce a `#Value error` if the cell is blank which is the whole point I need the `IFERROR`.

[image: Screenshot of my Sheet]

Comment: `=IFERROR(SUM(J14*K14)*(1-N14)+IF(O14="Y",50,0),"")`

Comment: If value is not `Y` your additional formula adds `""`. By replacing `""` with `0` it should work.